# If the image of $\omega$ under $X$ is always the same number, can $X$ be a random variable?

Tags: random-variable

Consider sample space $\Omega := \{\omega_1,\omega_2\,\dotsc,\omega_N\}$. Define mapping $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

A property of this $X$ is that $X(\omega_i) = 1$ for all $i \in \{1,\dotsc,N\}$.

Is $X$ a random variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, constants are random variables, just as constant functions are functions.

Comment: Ok, so do I now have it right that it's a random variable as long as its domain is $\Omega$ and its co-domain is $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Technically, one usually has the additional requirement that the function is measurable, that the preimage of any measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is a measurable subset of $\Omega$. This may require that you choose a sigma-algebra of measurable subsets of $\Omega$, but any such choice will make all constant functions measurable since the preimage of any set is either $\emptyset$ or $\Omega.$ Since you have numbered the elements you probably mean for $\Omega$ to be finite, and typically one uses the sigma-algebra of all subsets, and then all functions to $\mathbb{R}$ are random variables.

Comment: The notion of constant random variable leads to the degenerate distribution. More on this and on constant r.v.'s (as well as a.s. constant r.v.'s) you can find in wikipedia [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution)